# Statement Coverage vs Call Coverage

Tags: c, code-coverage

good day everyone, one of the required test quality metrics that we use for the C-Sources are statement and decision coverage. As the applied test tool does not provide the call coverage metric, can one argument that
100 % statement coverage of the given function implies 100% call coverage within this function ?

Comment: What's the formal definition for call coverage?

Comment: This looks more like a question for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/, isn't it?

Comment: the definition in the context of unit test for me is as following:
Call coverage metric measures the number of executed function calls at a program run as a percentage of the total number of calls that exist in that program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot make that assumption. A statement can include conditional calls:

```
float kelvin = celsius ? c2k(deg) : f2k(deg);
```

Covering that statement alone will not ensure that all calls are made.

PS: I once argued that that - if anything - full condition coverage (e.g. 100 % MC/DC) would give you the confidence of full call coverage. But I cannot find the blog article anymore.